# Notice: question on number of known digits of $\pi$ re-opened; now locked

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This is just to say that I have invoked my moderator powers to re-open this post

- [How many digits of $\pi$ are currently known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151938/1543)

The reason: after clarification by the OP in the comments and after Gerry Myerson edited the question accordingly, the question is no longer a duplicate of the question which it was closed as a duplicate of. (See the post edit history for clarification.)

---

*Edit June 4, 2012*: I've now locked the post due to behaviour described by Ilya in the comment which can also be seen by 10K+ users if they visit the post.

*Edit Jan 11, 2013*: Per Pavel M's answer below, I've unlocked the question.

Comment: Thanks for (also) cleaning up the comments...

Comment: I see your moderator powers also enable you to use a preposition to end a sentence with.

Comment: @Gerry, I'm afraid that this is the sort of vernacular English up with which you will have to put.

Comment: Rahul's comment is a variance of a quote by Winston Churchill.

Comment: @Graphth, [*misattributed* to Winston Churchill](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html).

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks for hitting me with some knowledge.

Comment: Just to update: [OP has answered his own question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/153299/5887) copying the content of the answer by skullpatrol. OP has accepted his own answer and used (presumably) another account of him to grant himself a bounty. I do agree, that at the current state the OP looks as a usual question on MSE - so that is not a reason to close the question. However, the situation evolves in a strange way.

Comment: @Willie: I propose deleting the question altogether.

Comment: As I said before, in my opinion the thread should have been deleted altogether.

Comment: @Asaf: and as I now unlocked the thread, you can feel free to go vote for that.

Comment: @WillieWong: No, I can't. Because the thread was closed at some point and I cannot recast my vote to close...

Answer (score 3):

Bumping this thread because I came across this question today doing some research on badges. It is one of **two** questions that earned the gold [Reversal](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/57/reversal) badge on Math.SE. (The other one, on the incredible [discovery of kalle-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/what-are-the-implications-of-the-discovery-of-the-kalle-numbers), spawned 3 such badges.)

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.

This notice makes it look like Math.SE has an ongoing dispute about the digits of $\pi$ which is raging on meta for seven months.

I propose to remove this scary notice, i.e., to unlock the question. The OP was last seen in July 2012. In any case, the matter had enough time to cool down.

Comment: I keep getting badges for posts about badges...

Comment: +1: could you get the revival badge for one/this question several times (due to meanwhile downvotes) ? (this is also a test...)

Comment: The implications of the discovery of the kalle-numbers are no longer available to mere mortals. They were "removed from Mathematics - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation."

Comment: @Martin: There is a version cached on Google, if you really want to read it.

Comment: @draks It would be a major oversight on the SE developers' part to allow cyclic actions (vote/unvote, delete/undelete) to have cumulative effect. Before awarding a badge, the systems checks whether the user already has too many. // As long as we are testing, could you (or someone else reading it) downvote my answer to [necromancer badge description](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7141/necromancer-badge-description/7142#7142)? I know I won't lose the badges, but don't know what will be shown on the pages listing my Enlightened and Nice Answer badges.

Comment: I downvoted the other answer.

Comment: Pavel, since @Martin already downvoted, should I or someone else upvote again?

Comment: @draks I'd rather keep it under 10, to see what exactly happens when I get another Nice Question or Enlightened thing.

Comment: I suggest that to ensure people don't incidentally vote that answer up to 10 or beyond without reading this or the comment there, we give more of a downvote cushion to the answer.  I've helped by changing my upvote to a downvote for a net -2.

Comment: I could upvote [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/7047/), but it would only take care of a nice answer badge, not an enlightened badge. Tell me whether I should do so or whether it would disrupt your experiment.

Comment: @Martin That'd be nice of you. :)

Comment: Here you are :)

Comment: @Martin Thanks. Now I'm confused. I was awarded the fifth [Nice Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=53153) badge, even though I did not deserve it after the earlier answer was downvoted. This is not how it was supposed to work...

Comment: Why did you *not deserve it after the earlier answer was downvoted*? I don't get it. When you 10 you'll get it. Basta. Where's the problem? Two more things: Are you a developper? Are experiments about how the system works or how to cheat on it ok?

Comment: @draks From [SO FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/206169): "suppose one of your answers received 10 up-votes, which caused you to earn the Nice Answer badge. After you have the badge, that same answer is down-voted to a score under 10. The Nice Answer badge is not revoked. However, the next time you have an answer that gets 10 up-votes, you will not earn an additional Nice Answer badge, because the system sees that you already have the number of Nice Answer badges that you should have." // But I did earn the fifth `Nice Answer` badge, contrary to the above.